# org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a project with authorization and sending confirmation (token) by email. I want to declare an object of type JavaMailSender, but the project does not see this dependency. Where can I find her?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId> </groupId>
    <artifactId> </artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name> </name>
    <description> </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <email.version>1.6.2</email.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev20210211-1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.23</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-mail -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.5</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you have an error message, I'm pretty sure you have one... Pls provide it.

Comment: Remove everything from the `dependencyManagement` section, except the `spring-cloud-dependencies`. Then add the `spring-boot-starter-mail` to the regular dependency section (if you need the `spring-integration-mail` one also add that).

Comment: You don't have `spring-boot-starter-mail` in the `dependencies` section, only in the `dependencyManagement`, where you should not have listed it, as the version should be controlled by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

if you work with maven, try add this to the pom

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I already wrote these dependencies in my pom.xml, but I still don't see
Maybe something else I missed?

Comment: reload/reimport the maven project, and use IDE or mvn dependency tree to check if the pom file is worked. also may check the local repository folder, if the target jar was downloaded successfully, sometimes network failure leads a problem, if no jar in folder, just delete it, let is download again